# Laravel - understand how testing works

Tags: laravel, testing

I am a beginner with the framework Laravel 5.2.

I want to understand how the unit test work. I made this test :

```
public function testPageLogin()
{
    $this->visit('/login')
    ->see('Connexion');
}
```

When I run the script : all is fine.

Then I made this test :

```
$this->visit('/login')
     ->type('toto.toto@gmail.com', 'email')
     ->type('toto', 'password')
     ->check('souvenir')
     ->press('Connexion')
     ->seePageIs('/login');
```

Of course the fields 'email', 'password', 'souvenir' exists in the html page. And with these values, the page "login" must be displayed because these values are not known into the DB.

When I run the script, I have a failure:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Co
> ntracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in C:\wamp\www\ecole\vendor
> \laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 748

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I still have the problem. Was my question not clear enough ? Do not hesitate to warn me is it was the case. thanks.

Comment: What does `vendor/bin/phpunit --version` print?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug within Laravel when using a later version of PHPUnit. I believe this bug still hasn't been fixed;

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10808

In the meantime, there's some workarounds below;

1) Instead of using the global PHPUnit, use `*project*/vendor/bin/phpunit`.

2) Downgrade your version of PHPUnit so that Laravel is compatible with it, to do this, run the below commands;

```
composer global remove phpunit/phpunit
composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit=~4.0'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried to remove and install phpunit 4.0, but I have a problem to do that. It is always 4.8 which is launched. I work on windows and do like that to launch my test : php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests/TestAuthentification.php

Comment: @user2672338 Sorry, I have no idea when it comes to Windows. Not sure if this helps http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/#comment-2817

Comment: Composer has problems with downgrading to lower package versions. You should try first chaning manually `phpunit` version in `composer.json`, removing `vendor/` directory and `composer.lock`, and then running `composer install`.

Comment: Tried to remove all the directory vendor/phpunit and re install phpunit via composer . Without success. I give up and wait the next laravel release (5.3) which seems resolved this issue. thanks for all.